# German Umlaute displaying wrong in ZIP-file created by Polar ZIPLight 5.0 in VB6

Tags: character-encoding, vb6, zip

I have this quite old code in VB6 that uses the ZIPLight 5.0 DLL by Polar for creating ZIPs.
It adds previously created PDFs from Crystal to ZIP-Files.

The problem is that on one customer system the german Umlaute are getting messed up and replaced with different (unicode?) chars. For example my filename has a german ä (U+00E4) in it but on a client machine it is displayed as an õ (U+00F5).

I wonder what might be the cause for this as it does not happen on our local testing systems. It might be some character set related circumstances.

Any hint would be great appreciated.

Comment: Zip file format does not use unicode for filenames. Probably default system locales (for non-unicode applications) are different on the encoding and decoding PCs. Try converting unicode filenames to [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) when encoding and in reverse when decoding (can use `WideCharToMultiByte` with first parameter 1252).

Comment: Ja, ja die Umlaute...^^ Maybe the program -which your customer wants to open the zip fil-e has trouble with the special characters. I know it from my work with Winzip.

Comment: @reporter: yes, but many different customers/people will open the zip file and I can't be prepared to "know" what charsets they will be using. How did you hande this?

Comment: @wqw: I think this is exactly the case. The locales, charsets etc on the systems are (gonna be) different. I'm not sure if I understand how to use this function. For example my filename has a german ä (U+00E4) in it but in a client machine it is displayed as an õ (U+00F5). How would I handle this ?

Comment: We handle it by using the first twenty six letters on alphabet. Sometimes it did hurt, though sometimes is less more (it generated less stress).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out [zip format](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) has an extension for unicode filenames support.

I did some research with [VszLib](https://github.com/wqweto/VszLib) and 7-zip does support unicode zip files when the `-mcu` parameter is set.

Here is my test sample with cyrillic filenames:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    With New cVszArchive
        .AddFile App.Path & "\това е проба.js"
        .CompressArchive App.Path & "\aaa_ascii.zip"
    End With
    With New cVszArchive
        .Parameter("cu") = "on"
        .AddFile App.Path & "\това е проба.js"
        .CompressArchive App.Path & "\aaa_unicode.zip"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    With New cVszArchive
        .OpenArchive App.Path & "\aaa_ascii.zip"
        .Extract App.Path & "\ascii"
        .OpenArchive App.Path & "\aaa_unicode.zip"
        .Extract App.Path & "\unicode"
    End With
End Sub
```

Unicode archive extracts correctly on non-cyrillic system locale (locale for non-unicode applications). `aaa_unicode.zip` has some troubles with XP's built-in zip viewer (newer OS's are ok) but VszLib extracts it with correct filenames on XP too.

You can check if ZIPLight component supports this extension -- a flag or parameter setting.